# PostgreSQL Hierarchical, category tree

Tags: postgresql, data-structures, postgresql-8.4, hierarchical-query, hierarchical-trees

ENV : postgresql-8.4

I'm trying to build a category tree . Basically I'm expecting a final output such :

```
categoryName 
categoryPath
leafcategory
```

e.g. :

```
Digital Camera
Electronics ::: Digital Camera 
true
```

The table structure is

```
CREATE TABLE categories (
    id  SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    categoryid bigint,
    categoryparentid bigint,
    categoryname text,
    status integer DEFAULT 0,
    lang text,
    eysiteid text,
    country text,
    tempid text,
    leafcategory boolean
);
```

So far I've got this but is not working. Any help would be highly appreciated :

```
WITH RECURSIVE tree (CategoryID, CategoryParentID, CategoryName, category_tree, depth) 
AS ( 
    SELECT 
        CategoryID,
        CategoryParentID,
        CategoryName,
        CategoryName AS category_tree,
        0 AS depth 
    FROM categories 
    WHERE CategoryParentID IS NULL 
UNION ALL 
    SELECT 
        c.CategoryID,
        c.CategoryParentID,
        c.CategoryName,
        tree.category_tree  || '/' || c.CategoryName AS category_tree,
        depth+1 AS depth 
    FROM tree 
        JOIN categories c ON (tree.category_tree  = c.CategoryParentID) 
) 
SELECT * FROM tree ORDER BY category_tree;
```

Sample from database

```
cat=> select * from categories;
  id   | categoryid | categoryparentid |          categoryname          | status | lang | eysiteid | country | tempid | leafcategory 
-------+------------+------------------+--------------------------------+--------+------+------------+---------+--------+--------------
     1 |         -1 |                0 | Root                           |      1 | en   | 0          | us      |        | f
     2 |      20081 |               -1 | Antiques                       |      1 | en   | 0          | us      |        | f
    17 |       1217 |            20081 | Primitives                     |      0 | en   | 0          | us      |        | t
    23 |      22608 |            20081 | Reproduction Antiques          |      0 | en   | 0          | us      |        | t
    24 |         12 |            20081 | Other                          |      0 | en   | 0          | us      |        | t
    25 |        550 |               -1 | Art                            |      1 | en   | 0          | us      |        | f
    29 |       2984 |               -1 | Baby                           |      1 | en   | 0          | us      |        | f
```

Comment: You have a strange way of marking the root nodes of the tree (normally one would have a NULL parent pointer for the roots). See my update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears you were joining on the wrong field.

```
 --  create some test data
DROP SCHEMA tmp CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA tmp ;
SET search_path=tmp;

CREATE TABLE categories
    -- ( id  SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
    ( categoryid SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
    , categoryparentid bigint REFERENCES categories(categoryid)
    , categoryname text
    -- , status integer DEFAULT 0
    -- , lang text
    -- , ebaysiteid text
    -- , country text
    -- , tempid text
    -- , leafcategory boolean
        );
INSERT INTO categories(categoryid,categoryparentid) SELECT gs, 1+(gs/6)::integer
FROM generate_series(1,50) gs;

UPDATE categories SET categoryname = 'Name_' || categoryid::text;
UPDATE categories SET categoryparentid = NULL WHERE categoryparentid <= 0;
UPDATE categories SET categoryparentid = NULL WHERE categoryparentid  >= categoryid;


WITH RECURSIVE tree (categoryid, categoryparentid, categoryname, category_tree, depth)
AS (
    SELECT
        categoryid
        , categoryparentid
        , categoryname
        , categoryname AS category_tree
        , 0 AS depth
    FROM categories
    WHERE categoryparentid IS NULL
UNION ALL
    SELECT
        c.categoryid
        , c.categoryparentid
        , c.categoryname
        , tree.category_tree  || '/' || c.categoryname AS category_tree
        , depth+1 AS depth
    FROM tree
        JOIN categories c ON tree.categoryid  = c.categoryparentid
    )
SELECT * FROM tree ORDER BY category_tree;
```

EDIT: the other ("non-function") notation for recursive seems to work better:

```
WITH RECURSIVE tree AS (
    SELECT
        categoryparentid AS parent
        , categoryid AS self
        , categoryname AS treepath
        , 0 AS depth
    FROM categories
    WHERE categoryparentid IS NULL
UNION ALL
    SELECT
        c.categoryparentid AS parent
        , c.categoryid AS self
        , t.treepath  || '/' || c.categoryname AS treepath
        , depth+1 AS depth
    FROM categories c
    JOIN tree t ON t.self  = c.categoryparentid
    )
SELECT * FROM tree ORDER BY parent,self
   ;
```

UPDATE: in the original query, you should replace

```
WHERE CategoryParentID IS NULL
```

by:

```
WHERE CategoryParentID = 0
```

or maybe even:

```
WHERE COALESCE(CategoryParentID, 0) = 0
```

Comment: must mention that the categoryparentid of the root category is 0 .

Comment: You must set the parent to NULL where parent <= 0; (or change the where clause in the first leg of the union)

Comment: I cannot find the actual error; the recursive fails here (pg 9.1.2) if I use the "functional" notation.

Comment: I think parent cannot be null because the type is bigint. Should I change the categoryparentid type to text ?

Comment: Absolutely not. A bigint type should be nullable (by default), just like an integer type, or any other type. BTW: it appears you already have too many candidate keys. What is the purpose of the ID field ?

Comment: There may be duplicates of categoryId(s) so that's why I added an unique "id" field. Seems that the NULL fixed the function as now works.

Comment: That is *essentially* a normalisation problem. If there are possibly more items that belong to a category, the {category, parentcategory, categoryname} and the {item, categoryid, itemname} should be in two separate tables with an 1:N relationship. (otherwise the {category, parentcategory} pairs would repeat in the single table)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/3225313) it is more or less what you want to do. In your case I would better have used [LTree materialized path Postgresql's extension](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/ltree.html).